# Почему не выполняется данное условие? Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Всем привет! Считываю первый столбец таблицы, в нем периодически встречаются склеенные ячейки. В первом слоте такой ячейки лежит значение, а далее только `None`. Но в соответствующих ячейках в других столбцах есть значения, которые нужно обрабатывать. Ниже приведен код с проблемой

```
if (str(sheet['A' + str(i)].value).replace('\xa0', '') == "None"):
                j = i
                while(str(sheet['A' + str(i)].value).replace('\xa0', '') == "None"):
                    count_None += 1
                    dict_otv_len[str(sheet['A' + str(i - count_None)].value).replace('\xa0', ' ')] += str(sheet['E' + str(j)].value)
                    dict_otv_len[str(sheet['A' + str(i - count_None)].value).replace('\xa0', ' ')] += ";"
                    dict_otv_district[str(sheet['A' + str(i - count_None)].value).replace('\xa0', ' ')] += str(sheet['O' + str(j)].value)
                    dict_otv_district[str(sheet['A' + str(i - count_None)].value).replace('\xa0', ' ')] += ";" 
                    j += 1
if (str(sheet['A' + str(i)].value).replace('\xa0', '') != "None"):
                count_None = 0
```

Пытался разобраться в отладчике, но ничего не пойму. Первое условие никогда не выполняется ( а второе - всегда), хотя в соответствующих ячейках лежат None.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в ячейке находится __строка__ `"None"`, а не значение `None`?

Comment: Я пробовал и со значением None, но в последней версии программы стал явно приводить значения ячейке к строке. Спасибо за комментарий